# SQL Alchemy: understanding expire_on_commit

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I was trying to understand the behavior of `Session`'s [expire_on_commit](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.params.expire_on_commit) parameter.

So I created a small program which adds 2 rows, updates one of them and then accesses the other:

```
engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///tmp.db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=True)
session = Session()

# add 2 users
u1 = User(name="u1")
u2 = User(name="u2")
session.add(u1)
session.add(u2)
session.commit()

# update a user
u1.name = "new name"
session.commit()

print("=== access a user ===")
print(u2.name)
```

Output when `expire_on_commit` is `True` (default):

```
2018-07-13 13:38:14,478 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2018-07-13 13:38:14,478 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2018-07-13 13:38:14,479 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2018-07-13 13:38:14,479 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2018-07-13 13:38:14,479 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA table_info("users")
2018-07-13 13:38:14,479 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2018-07-13 13:38:14,480 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
CREATE TABLE users (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        name VARCHAR, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


2018-07-13 13:38:14,480 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2018-07-13 13:38:14,488 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2018-07-13 13:38:14,490 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2018-07-13 13:38:14,491 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (?)
2018-07-13 13:38:14,491 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('u1',)
2018-07-13 13:38:14,491 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (?)
2018-07-13 13:38:14,491 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('u2',)
2018-07-13 13:38:14,492 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2018-07-13 13:38:14,497 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2018-07-13 13:38:14,497 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT users.id AS users_id 
FROM users 
WHERE users.id = ?
2018-07-13 13:38:14,497 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (1,)
2018-07-13 13:38:14,498 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine UPDATE users SET name=? WHERE users.id = ?
2018-07-13 13:38:14,498 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('new name', 1)
2018-07-13 13:38:14,499 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
=== access a user ===
2018-07-13 13:38:14,504 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2018-07-13 13:38:14,504 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.name AS users_name 
FROM users 
WHERE users.id = ?
2018-07-13 13:38:14,505 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (2,)
u2
```

Output when `expire_on_commit` is `False`:

```
...
=== access a user ===
u2
```

So far it's as I expected: with `expire_on_commit`, the next access following a commit emits a SQL query, while when `expire_on_commit` is off, there is no SQL query.

Now, I wanted to create an example where an access after a commit provides an out-of-date data.

So instead of updating the first user directly

```
u1.name = "new name"
```

I updated all users using `update`:

```
session.query(User).update({'name': "new name"})
```

Output:

```
...
=== access a user ===
new name
```

There is no SQL query, but surprisingly the value is correct.
I expected the update to be processed by the database itself and therefore the cached object not to be aware of the change.
What do I miss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default value for the [`Query.update()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update) parameter [`synchronize_session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update.params.synchronize_session) is 'evaluate' which, according to the docs:

> Evaluate[s] the Query’s criteria in Python straight on the objects in the
>   session.

If you call `update()` like this:

```
session.query(User).update({'name': "new name"}, synchronize_session=False)
```

the objects in the session will remain untouched although the DB changes:

```
...
=== access a user ===
u2
```